# C# Main Form called every time I make a new form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this very strange bug... Whenever i make a new form inside my main class, main form is called as well... For example, if I do something like this:

```
    private void Player_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Options options = new Options(categoryList, stationList, styleManager1, 0, this);
    }
```

the main form is showed as well... I mean, the original one, plus the new one... Its not the Options class constructor, i checked it... Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: `Its not the Options class constructor` -> unless the strange thing does still  happen when you comment the line you posted. Otherwise I'm sure that it's the Options class constructor. You may not be able to see it but someone here may.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Options is an MDI child form, and your main form is the MDI parent.

If not - put a breakpoint on your main form's Activate or Load events and look at the stack trace - this will tell you how & where it's being triggered.